# Query for inserting value to the newly created column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE #employee
(
    employee_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    doj DATE ,
    dob DATE 
)

INSERT INTO #employee (employee_code, employee_name, doj, dob)
SELECT '1', 'sabith', '01/01/2015', '01/01/1990' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'siraj', '01/01/2016', '01/01/1991' 

CREATE TABLE #emp_leave_tables 
(
    employee_code VARCHAR(50),
    leave_ref_no VARCHAR(50), 
    req_date date,
    leave_from_date date,
    leave_to_date date
)

INSERT INTO #emp_leave_tables (employee_code, leave_ref_no, req_date, leave_from_date, leave_to_date)
SELECT '1', '1001', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', '01/05/2020' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '1001', '01/01/2020', '01/01/2020','06/01/2020'
```

I want to create a temp table #result and a new column no_days to count he employee's number of leave units and I want to insert the value into the temp table

Comment: What's the question? You shouldn't be using localized strings to insert dates anyway as their meaning varies from one locale to another. What would `04/07/2020` mean? Use the unambiguous unseparated format instead, ie `20200407` for April 7th

Comment: As for inserting multiple values, you don't need SELECT and UNION ALL. Use the `VALUES` clause with multiple rows in parentheses, ie `VALUES ('1',....), ('2',....)`

Comment: I want to find Employee taken maximum and minimum number of leave units by inserting this values to a temp table

Comment: create table temp_table (
    employee_code varchar(50) primary key,
    leave_units smallint
)

insert into temp_table values(
    select e.employee_code, max(DATEDIFF(day, el.leave_to_date, el.leave_from_date)) as maximum, min(DATEDIFF(day, el.leave_to_date, el.leave_from_date)) as minimum
    from emp_leaves_table e
    group by e.employee_code)

Comment: What. is a "leave unit"?  Nothing in your data is called a "unit".

Answer (score -1):

For creating the new `temp` table, try this:

```
create table temp_table (
    employee_code varchar(50) primary key,
    leave_units smallint
);
```

Then, you may use this to populate the table:

```
insert into temp_table
values (
    select e.employee_code
        , max(DATEDIFF(day, el.leave_to_date, el.leave_from_date)) as maximum
        , min(DATEDIFF(day, el.leave_to_date, el.leave_from_date)) as minimum
    from emp_leaves_table e
    group by e.employee_code
);
```

Comment: i need to count the number of days " leave from date to leave to date " and i need to insert this value into a temp table column for finding the maximum and minimum number of leave taken by the employee

Comment: @sirajk checkout the edited query, this should give the max and minimum number of days each employee took leave for.

Comment: shows like this  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @singh.rbir you don't use the keyword `values` when you are selecting the data...